# Rate issue in Trade agreement journal

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I have created multiple journals for an item (suppose "item1") in AX2012 with multiple rates and different from and to date. 
Like for Journal 1, From date is set as 1/12/2013 and to date is NULL and rate as 50.
for journal 2, From date is set as 7/12/2013 and to date is NULL and rate as 60.

Now, logically when selecting item in sales line form on or after 07/12/2013, I must get unit price 60. But unit price that i am getting is 50.

How to get latest price of an item, account, to, from date in sales line form?

Comment: I dont think this is a programming question - however I think I know the answer - you need a to date to expire the first rate, ie 1/12/2013 - 6/12/2013

Answer (score 1):

It is valid in AX to have more than one active price record (`PriceDiscTable`).

In your case both 50 and 60 are valid rates, it then does the service of choosing the lesser one! 
In journal 2 you should find the old rate, then apply an end date of 06/12/2013.

As this is cumbersome, it is a usual customization to auto-close prices. This could be done in the `insert` method of `PriceDiscTable`.